# SQL joins in Entity Framework (WPF MVVM)

Tags: sql, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, ef-code-first

I want to do a simple join with raw sql using Entity Framework.

My model-classes are defined as follows:

```
public class Price
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    public int ProductId {get; set;}
    public double Price {get; set;}
    public virtual Product Product {get; set;}
}
    public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Price> Price {get; set;}
}
```

My PriceContext class as follows:

```
public class PriceContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet<Price> Prices {get; set;}
public DbSet<Product> Products {get; set;}

public PriceContext() : base("ConnectionString") {}

public List<Price> FindAll()
{
    string sqlQuery= @"select products.name, prices.[type], prices.[from], prices.price, prices.pricelistname  from products, prices where prices.productid = products.id;

    return Prices.SqlQuery(sqlQuery).ToList<Price>();
}
}
```

My ViewModel has a method as follows:

```
public void FindAll()
    {
        var context = new PriceContext();
        var prices = context.FindAll();
        ObservablePrices = new ObservableCollection<Price>(prices);
    }
```

My WPF view runs `ViewModel.FindAll()` whenever it loads and also has a `DataGrid` element bound to `ObservablePrices`.

The query `sqlQuery`does not seem to work. If I however change it to `select * from prices` it works fine (just to see that all my bindings etc. are working as intended). I can't seem to query the table `products` from within this context.

Comment: you should not be resetting the observable prices every time.  you only need to populate it with your items. :

Answer (score 1):

eliminates the method you have in your DbContext and takes a methodo of type List.

```
pública static List<Price> FindAll()
{
    using (var context = new PriceContext())
    {
          var sqlQuery = from a in context.products
                         join b in context.prices
                         on a.id equals b.productid
                         select a;
    }
    return sqlQuery;
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx for future reference on more complex joins